# Jquery "nth-child" Issues

Tags: jquery

I have a list of items, ten in total and will have more however...

I've got a "sorting" function which allows the user to view items by "price" or "alphabetically".

This works fine, the issue I'm having is the selector line I'm using to get 5th child within the list is bugging out.

Here is the line of code:

```
$("#list-category-results li:nth-child(5n)").css("margin-right", "0");
```

Also, here is a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/De8Ku/1483/) of my current progress.

When you click on "price" or "alphabetical" the placement of the "margin-right: 0" doesn't stay on 5th element and I have no idea why??

Comment: Your jQuery selector isn't a CSS selector. It applies the style directly to the matched elements (at the time it is called).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can bind to the `click` event of the sort buttons and remove the `margin-right` value for all `li` and reapply to the fifth item like so:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // Apply margin-right: 0 on DOM Ready //
    $("#list-category-results li:nth-child(5n)").css("margin-right", "0");    

    // Update margin-right on Sorting of Elements //
    $('.btnSort').bind('click', function(){
        $("#list-category-results li").css('margin-right', '');
        $("#list-category-results li:nth-child(5n)").css("margin-right", "0");
    });
});
```

[Updated JSFIddle Here](http://jsfiddle.net/De8Ku/1488/)

I hope this helps!

Comment: This works however, I need the margin-right to take effect on page load, not onclick

Answer (score 4):

You need to re-do this line:

```
$("#list-category-results li:nth-child(5n)").css("margin-right", "0");
```

every time you sort.

In won't just happen automagically just because you've re-ordered the children, unless it's in your CSS rules.  Using jQuery to add CSS styles *directly* adds those styles to specific elements, and those elements will *retain* those styles if they're moved around the DOM tree.

Hence you will also need to remove those CSS style for the items that have changed position, e.g.:

```
$("#list-category-results li")
    .css('margin-right', '')      // clear all <li> margins
    .filter(':nth-child(5n)')
    .css('margin-right', '0px');  // set every 5th <li> margin
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer - I don't quite understand it though?